# Youcanpay API php issue

Tags: php, payment-gateway

Here is theSDK of youcanpay payment gateway https://github.com/NextmediaMa/youcan-payment-php-sdk

I have followed the documentation described in the above link. And the payment form is displaying fine but I need to generate a token to proceed with the payments. But in the token generating step php not able to find youcanpay class intances which is used as static method
 `YouCanPay::setIsSandboxMode(true);`. I simply want to be sure I didn't do anything wrong. May be there was an issue with my folder structure here it's screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/RosMn.png. Or I have to change php namcspace? `use YouCan\Pay\YouCanPay;`

**Form display HTML**

```
  <div id="error-container"></div>
    <div id="payment-card"></div>
    <button id="pay">Pay</button>
```

```
** php **
use YouCan\Pay\YouCanPay;

class ExamplePayment
{
    
    /**
     * Return a token to make payment for an order, this token is required to make payment with JS script.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function createToken()
    {

        // Enable sandbox mode, otherwise delete this line.
        YouCanPay::setIsSandboxMode(true);

        // Create a YouCan Pay instance, to retrieve your private and public keys login to your YouCan Pay account
        // and go to Settings and open API Keys.
          $youCanPay = YouCanPay::instance()->useKeys('pri_sandbox_56cfe571-f671-42a6-a231-d58ec', 'pub_sandbox_a62be70f-d585-4e88-9c5b-563f2');
        // $youCanPay = YouCanPay::instance()->useKeys('pri_sandbox_56cfe571-f671-42a6-a231-d58ec', 'pub_sandbox_a62be70f-d585-4e88-9c5b-563f2');

        // Data of the customer who wishes to make this purchase.
        // Please keep these keys.
    
        // Create the order you want to be paid
        $token = $youCanPay->token->create(
            // String orderId (required): Identifier of the order you want to be paid.
            "order-id",
            // Integer amount (required): The amount, Example: 25 USD is 2500.
            "2000",
            // String currency (required): Uppercase currency.
            "USD",
            // String customerIP (required): Customer Address IP.
            "175.107.236.174",
            // String successUrl (required): This URL is returned when the payment is successfully processed.
            "https://smmpanelauto.com/orders-status/success",
            // String errorUrl (required): This URL is returned when payment is invalid.
            "https://smmpanelauto.com/orders-status/error"
        );

        echo $token->getId();
    }
    
}
```

```
********** JS Code **********
   <script type="text/javascript">
        // Create a YouCan Pay instance.
        const ycPay = new YCPay('pub_sandbox_a62be70f-d585-4e88-9c5b-563f2', {
            formContainer: '#payment-card',
            locale: 'en',
            isSandbox: true,
            errorContainer: '#error-container',
            // token: 'token_x6gf0_....'
        });

        // render the form
        ycPay.renderCreditCardForm();
        
        // start the payment on button click
        var el = document.getElementById('pay');
        if(el){
            <?php   
                 $a = new ExamplePayment; 
                ?>
            el.addEventListener('click', function(){
                  // execute the payment
                  ycPay.pay("<?php $a->createToken(); ?>") //using token
                    .then(successCallback)
                    .catch(errorCallback);
                });
        }
        function successCallback(response) {
          console.log(rsponse);
        }
        
        function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log(rsponse);
        }
    </script>
```

When I use `<?php $a->createToken(); ?>` the form is not showing. otherwise. it's shows the following error **There are invalid fields in your request, please verify your inputs and try again** But all inputs are filled.

Comment: What specific error message are you seeing?

Comment: When I use ``` <?php $a->createToken(); ?> ``` the form is not showing. otherwise. 
***it's shows the following error There are invalid fields in your request, please verify your inputs and try again.***
But we must have to generate a token in order to payment success.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show, in context, where you're using that, and also provide the error message within the question. Don't bury important info in the comments. The question should contain a [mre] of the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson Question revised.

Comment: Thanks, but like I said, you need to show your usage of that code **in context**. We don't know what your form is or how the token might affect it.

Comment: I have shown all the things above.

Comment: Where exactly in the form are you echoing the token? You need to show it as one example. You only showed one little bit of the form

Comment: _"But in the token generating step php not able to find youcanpay class intances"_ - what exactly do you mean by that? Do you get an error message? If so, please quote it verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the createToken() method it causes the PHP fatal error, and the server responds with 500 HTTP status or the blank page. To see the exact error you may check the logs, of for the dev environment just add these lines in the beginning of the PHP code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1)
```

So that all the PHP errors are sent to the output and displayed ob the page.

Looking into the file structure I assume all the PHP/HTML/JS code is located in the single `index.php` file. So make sure the YouCanPay SDK's file are included, i.e. you should have the line like this in the beginning if the file (or anywhere before teh actual usage of the `YouCanPay` class):

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```